# WorkFlow Host Error

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

i have MVC application as client application for WCF workflow service. i sent email from Workflow which is having workflow instance id along with approve and decline link. Clicking on approve and decline link will call MVC controller and controller should call workflow to resume the execution.but when i get following error :Operation 'Approve|{http://tempuri.org/}IService' on service instance with identifier 'e58853c9-0166-4560-8085-be183710c6a4' cannot be performed at this time. Please ensure that the operations are performed in the correct order and that the binding in use provides ordered delivery guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the xaml for your workflow service? It sounds like it's trying to access the workflow before it's created, or some such thing-

Comment: i got to know that i m getting this error because of i am not accessing WCF Workflow in Sequence but prob is that i want to resume workflow from between the workflow.what should be done in order to do so ?